# application unable to access db when deployed on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to deploy an application on ocp kuberbetes cluster, but it needs db connection. Db is placed outside the kubernetes cluster.

I am getting below error :

````
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: krfoddps : Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301) ~[?:?]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:945) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]```


**Below is code from application.properties:**

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://krfoddps:3330/school
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=rootpass
````